# Problems with Leaflet Layers

Tags: leaflet

I am using Leaflet with OpenLayers and I have the following code:

The all code I used is the following :

```
OSMaps = tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution:
    'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
  maxZoom: 50,
  detectRetina: true,
});

wMaps = tileLayer(
  "https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}",
  {
    maxZoom: 30,
    detectRetina: true,
    attribution:
      "Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community",
  }
);
dMaps = tileLayer(
  "https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png",
  {
    attribution:
      '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attributions">CARTO</a>',
    subdomains: "abcd",
    maxZoom: 30,
  }
);

// Marker center of France
center = marker([46.4547, 2.2529], {
  icon: icon({
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [13, 41],
    iconUrl: require("../../../../../../node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png"),
    shadowUrl: require("../../../../../../node_modules/leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png"),
  }),
});

// Layers
devicesLayer = new LayerGroup();
options = {
  layers: [this.OSMaps],
  //zoom: 50
  minZoom: 0,
  maxZoom: 50,
};

layersControl = {
  baseLayers: {
    "Wikimedia Maps": this.wMaps,
    "Night Maps": this.dMaps,
    "Street Maps": this.OSMaps,
  },
  overlays: {},
};
```

The way of adding points is the following :

```
device_marker = marker(deviceLatLng, {
  icon: icon({
    iconSize: [32, 46],
    iconAnchor: [22, 46],
    iconUrl,
  }),
  //title: item.name
  //Aqui de pone el titulo
});

this.markersMap.push(device_marker);
this.map.addLayer(this.markerMap);
```

When I try to set Leaflet in a map and I set zoom to the map I obtain the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

Comment: You can't use Leaflet and Openlayers together, really - they have two (quite) different architectures (and I suspect you meant OSM instead of OL). Furthermore, that little code is not enough to know what's going on - please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry for my error. It is OSM instead of OL. The all code I used is the following :

Comment: That's not [vanilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software) JS; you're using some kind of framework (angular? vue?) but you're not telling which one, and also you're not telling how the map is initialized. Make sure that your code is fully reproducible.

Comment: An [adapted vanilla working example of your code](https://plnkr.co/edit/Jq9ahfk7NfA4OM89) works OK, besides the fact that you're setting a value `maxZoom` way too high for the given tile sources.

Comment: Hello , I am using Angular for my code

Comment: I have tested that code and when I execute the openStreet Map I still have the following error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()